# What's the correct use of variadic function template here?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-functions

I happen to compute the elapsed running time of various functions and algorithms in my research project, so, I decided to define an `elapsed_time` function which might take various type of functions with various number of arguments(if any) and also various return types or none (`void`).

I want to pass a function to this `elapsed_time` function and make use of a function pointer, pointing to the function that has been passed as an argument of the `elapsed_time` function, and thus compute its elapsed running time.
I am not sure if my code is even close to be correct, but I did my best as a newbie in programming, as follows:

**MWE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<class return_type, class  ... argument_types>
void elapsed_time(return_type func(argument_types ... args)){

    return_type (* func_ptr)(argument_types ... args) = & func;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start_;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end_;

    start_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    /* Put the Function whose elapsed time matter right HERE */
    func_ptr(); /// What to pass here?
    /* Put the Function whose elapsed time matter right HERE */



    end_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time (end_ - start_);
    const double seconds(elapsed_time.count());
    cout << "\nRuntime: " << seconds << " s\n\n";
}
```

and now lest consider I have a function to be passed to elapsed_time function, as follows:

```
vector<Point_CCS_xy> fun(const vector<Point_CCS_xy> point_vec, const Point_CCS_xy inquiry_pnt, const int sz);
```

where `Point_CCS_xy` is a class of cartesian coordinates (x,y), i.e.,

```
struct Point_CCS_xy {
    long double x_coordinate;
    long double y_coordinate;

};
```

My questions:

1. Is the function I have written correct? what should I pass to func_ptr() as commented in the body of the `elapsed_time` function? Passing `argument_types ... args` leads to the error: `'argument_types' does not refer to a value`
2. In the main(), how to pass `vector<Point_CCS_xy> fun(const vector<Point_CCS_xy> point_vec, const Point_CCS_xy inquiry_pnt, const int sz);` function to the `elapsed_time` function?

In advance, I appreciate that you share your thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following approach

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void elapsed_time(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start_;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end_;

    start_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    end_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time (end_ - start_);
    const double seconds(elapsed_time.count());
    cout << "\nRuntime: " << seconds << " s\n\n";
}
```

In the above I make the entire function type a single template parameter.  This has the advantage of allowing you to pass any type of callable object, not just function pointers.  I then use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to actually call the passed in object as it is design to handle invoke any callable with the provided arguments.

So for your `fun` function, you would pass it to this version of the `elapsed_time` like

```
elapsed_time(fun, point_vec, inquiry_pnt, sz);
```

If the callable you are passing happens to be an overloaded function, then you would just need to wrap that call in a lambda expression like

```
elapsed_time([&](){ fun(point_vec, inquiry_pnt, sz); });
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I actually I can also learn two `std` methods functionality here `std::invoke` and `std::forward`.

Comment: @BMB Starting in C++14 the return type can be left off as it can be deduced from the function body.  In this example, there is no return statement in the body of the lambda, so it returns void.  If I had instead used `return fun(point_vec, inquiry_pnt, sz);` then the return type would be deduced as the return type of `fun`

Comment: @NathanOlivier Thanks Nathan, it was an answer with a few more tips, very informative.